# I am creating a website in ASP.Net using MasterPage

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a website in ASP.Net using MasterPage . I need Help for using different page title on each page .

eg: My Company : Home

and  My Compant : offerings  on my second page how to do using a MasterPage

Answer (score 1):

Master

```
...
<title>
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContentPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</title>
...
```

Content

```
...
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContentPlaceHolder" runat="server" ID="TitleContent">
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="TitleLabel"></asp:Literal>
</asp:Content>
...
```

Content codeBehind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    TitleLabel.Text = "Some title";
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a section on your child page as follows

```
  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
  </asp:Content>
```

You can put anything in-between which you write in the `head` section.

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
          CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" Title="Untitled Page" %>
```

here you can set the title in the page directive
or on the code behind

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Page.Title = "Master Page ";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use codebehind to give title to your content pages..

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 Page.Title="your title";
 }
```

This is the easiest way which you can follow..